# How do i do comments in PLY

Tags: python, regex, ply

How do I do comments in ply. I am making an interpreter in PLY called calico. One problem I am experiencing is comments. They should look like `\\\\this\\\\`. However, I have some trouble implementing them. Here is the calico source code

```
...
\\inheritance and polymorphism\\;
public class Main(){
    public static main() {
        println("test"); \\hello world\\;
        me = class Person(11, "a", "b", "11/09/09"); \\objects\\;
        println(me.get_details());
        me.tax(); \\encapsulation\\;
        println(me.get_details());
        me2 = class Employee(11, "a", "b", "11/09/09", "n", "11/09/35", 1000)
    }
};
```

The comment token should look like this `\\\\inheritance and polymorphism\\\\` but instead it looks like this \\inheritance and polymorphism\\;public class Main(){    public static main() {        println...
I have tried to do it like this `t_COMMENT = r"\\\\.*\\\\"` but that has not work I have also tried it like this

```
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'(/\\(.|\n)*?\\/)|(//.*)'
    pass
```

Comment: The comment doesn't need forward slashes but they are in the regular expression. They should be removed.

Comment: I am not used to python regex string so please clarify an example of this. also this `r'(/\\(.|\n)*?\\/)|(.*)'`raises this error message Regular expression for rule 't_COMMENT' matches empty string

Comment: I mainly meant the forward slashes in the first parentheses (was unclear, sorry). I don't know what the parentheses after `|` should actually match (C-like single line comments?).

Comment: And regarding the backslashes the first approach with four consecutive slashes instead of two was right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you test your regex separately, in a standalone website like `regex101.com`

Here is a [link to the regex](https://regex101.com/r/3iDEHz/1) described below.

I tested this string to declare comments:

```
(\\\\(.|\n)*?\\\\)
```

And I was able to get three matches for

```
\\ a multiline
comment \\
print (a)
\\inheritance and polymorphism\\;print ("ab");\\b\\;print("end")
```

namely

```
\\ a multiline
comment \\
```

and

```
\\inheritance and polymorphism\\
```

and

```
\\b\\
```

According to regex101, it needs the doubled backslash because

> \ matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)

According to regex101, it needs the `(.|\n)*?` because

> 2nd Capturing Group (.|\n)*?
>
> *? matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Comment: Just so you know, my interpreter removes all \n before getting parsed and tokenized

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `*` is a greedy match, which means it will consume more than it needs to: For example lets say we have this line of code `\\a\\;print("ab");\\b\\;print("end")` the comment token will spit out from the first `\\` to the last `\\` AND everything in between making the comment token look like this `\\a\\;print("ab");\\b\\` which is bad.

Using the `?`on the `*` operator for turning the greedy operator into a lazy operator meaning that the comment token will spit out from the first `\\` to the next `\\` stop make the token and find a another comment, the final output is split into 2, just as it should be. 1.`\\a\\` 2.`\\b\\`

Using `?` on this `*` makes it lazy, doing what it wants me to do

the fixed code is this `\\\\.*?\\\\`, if you want more details about greedy and lazy operators got to this [question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could improve this answer by quoting the salient portions of the link (since links can go stale) and by placing the correct regex in your answer (to make it a one-stop question and answer for future users).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have now edited my code according to you request. Any and all feedback is welcome